# Accept null values but not by default in a MySql column

Tags: mysql, null

I just can't can find an answer for my question. If there is on stack overflow, just post it and I will delete my post.

My problem:

I want to accept `null` values in a mysql column, but not by default. When I insert a row I should also set a value for that column and that should be required.

Right now, in phpmyadmin, if I check *Null* field (to accept `null` values), the field *Default* (default value) will be automatically set with `null` value. That means that I can omit to set a value for that column in an `insert` query and it will be filled automatically with a `null` value.

When did I say a column should be auto-filled if is not set ? I said to accept null values, not to be auto-filled.

Do I miss something ?

Comment: What should the value be by default instead?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen No value. It should be required on an `insert` query.

Comment: So you want this _not_ to accept nulls on insert, but accept nulls on update?

Comment: @raina77ow He wants to require the `INSERT` to specify the value of the column, not allow it to be defaulted.

Comment: @Barmar Exactly.

Comment: The type of field you want then is NULL (no other option at database level to accept NULLs, and you must implement that restriction in your SQL insert code, always including that field in the INSERT query). The DEFAULT value is only used when you do not include that field in the INSERT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a column has the `NULL` attribute, and you don't specify an explicit `DEFAULT` attribute, it's as if you defined it with `DEFAULT NULL`. This is specified in the documentation of ["Implicit Default Handling"](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-type-defaults.html):

> If the column can take NULL as a value, the column is defined with an explicit DEFAULT NULL clause.

If you want to prevent omitting the column when inserting, I think you can do it by specifying a `DEFAULT` expression that causes an error. This requires you to be using at least version 8.0.13 of MySQL, because prior to this the `DEFAULT` had to be a literal, not an expression.

Comment: I wonder can one overcome the limitation of 8.0.13 by setting up a default value that never gets used in (easier for numbers, much harder for texts), then having an insert/update trigger discarding this value.

Comment: Is "specifying a DEFAULT expression that causes an error" a good way to do that ? Isn't a bad practice ?

Comment: @Andrei You want the attempted `INSERT` to get an error if they don't specify the column, don't you? The DB doesn't have any "good practice" for this.

Comment: @raina77ow I don't know how a trigger can tell whether the `INSERT` query has an explicit value for the column.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting [the docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-type-defaults.html):

> Implicit Default Handling
>
> If a data type specification includes no explicit DEFAULT value, MySQL determines the default value as follows:
> If the column can take NULL as a value, the column is defined with an
> explicit DEFAULT NULL clause.

So if your column is nullable, it *always* has a default value - whether set explicitly (by `DEFAULT ...` clause) or implicitly (like described above).

As @Barmar noticed, there's (at least in theory) a way to handle this with providing an always-failing DEFAULT expression (since MySQL 8.0.13 allowing it).

An alternative (available on versions before 8.0.13) is setting up a DEFAULT  value that never should be put in your column anyway AND creating an pre-insert trigger checking the inserted value against this special case.

The benefit of this approach is you're more flexible in providing specific errors for that case. The downside is the value you might consider special will end up being actually used by real-world scenarios, causing a really weird bug. That's easier to prevent for numbers (0 for unsigned IDs, etc.), but much harder to do with user-created strings and similar entities.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by creating a column that accepts a null, and then applying a trigger BEFORE INSERT that checks for null.

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE `testNulls` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nullField` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_UNIQUE` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 ;
```

Now create a trigger

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `testNulls_BEFORE_INSERT` BEFORE INSERT ON `testNulls` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  if (new.nullField is null) then  
      signal sqlstate '45000' set message_text = 'Cannot insert NULL in nullField';
      END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Attemppting to insert a NULL in the `nullField` column will return an error 45000, but updating a row to contain NULL will succeed.

Tested with MySQL 8
Demo: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8eV4VihbeB5woEYwuGMFvK/0

Comment: but they don't want to prevent nulls from being inserted, just prevent having the column name not be specified on the insert